# Will "Stack Signature for the dump..." appear in the SQL Server error log every time there is a memory dump?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am currently monitoring sql server memory dumps as they appear in the error log. All I really need to know is if this occurred, I can find out the details another way.

Right now my logic is that if the string "Stack Signature for the dump" appears in the log, this indicates that a memory dump event has occurred. I am trying to confirm that this happens every time a memory dump occurs, regardless of what comes after.

I know there is the dmv that has this information, but our logging platform can only look at the sql server error log at the moment.

I am going with this string from the error log instead of other ones because I have noticed that sometimes it doesn't log that a dump file was created, but I see one happen. For example:

This appears in the error log with the address to a dump file

```
Stack Signature for the Dump is 0x0000000000000002342
*Short Stack Dump
****************
**
*BEGIN STACK DUMP:
**
****************
*Stack Dump being sent to C\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\LOG\SQLDump002.txt
**Dump thread spid 0, EC = 0X000000000000000\
```

This doesn't appears in the error log, with no address to the dump file:

```
Stack Signature for the Dump is 0x000000000000000654
*Short Stack Dump
****************
**
Non-yielding scheduker
*
*BEGIN STACK DUMP:
**
****************
*Unable to get thread context for spid 0
```

In both cases, the memory dump shows up in sys.dm_server_memory_dumps. But the fact that the second scenario create a dump file without indicating it in the error log makes me question if "Stack Signature" is 100% reliable as well.
So, is there eve a case where a memory dump would occur in SQL server and it would not appear in the error log as a "stack signature"?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you please add the output of `select @@version` in the question.

Comment: The first one is 2016 and the second one is 2008, but we have a wide range of versions in our environment. Are you saying that we can rely on the "Stack Signature for the Dump" to occur for every instance of a memory dump so long as it is a later version?